# How far behind a woman can a man walk?

Tags: halacha, women

The gemara in Pesachim (iirc perek 10 or so) says it is forbidden to walk behind a woman on the street, to avoid unwanted thoughts.

Behind is quite loose - is there a "safe distance"? What is it?

Comment: The Terumas HaDeshen and R' Shlomo Zalman Auerbach say this doesn't apply today, by the way -- you'll just encounter another woman a few paces later. That Gemara was talking about when it was unusual to encounter one.

Comment: See: https://dinonline.org/2011/10/02/walking-behindbetween-women/

Comment: @Shmuel write it up and get the points :) otherwise I will, thanks very much for the reference

Comment: I think it's quite loose for a reason. I'd say a "safe distance" would be far enough away that he is unconscious of her being [a woman and] in front of him, or at least unlikely to be aroused by her presence (to the state of having unwanted thoughts). In my opinion, that would be different for different [levels of] men. On the other hand, as the usual advice is to quicken one's pace, and get in front of the woman, then the "safe distance" would be one that would make getting in front of her realistically unfeasible (which would depend on the specifics of the situation).

Comment: @RabbiKaii Thanks, hoped it helped! Gut Shabbos!

Comment: @TamirEvan the "leave it up to the individual depending on their level" approach might be similar to the [Ritva end of Kiddushin](https://www.sefaria.org/Ritva_on_Kiddushin.81a.6)?

Comment: Said tongue-in-cheek, if you accept the principle of the curvature of space (עולם העגולים) it's implication is that if you walk behind a woman "far enough", you will be walking in front of her. Somewhere in this seems to be a sideways reference to פנים לאחור and פנים לפנים. Shabbat shalom, my friend.

Comment: @RabbiKaii Yes, I was thinking along similar lines. _Baruch she-Kivanti le-Da'at Gadol_.

Comment: @TamirEvan contrast with the Rebbe Rashab who said that if a person thinks he can look at a woman because it doesn't affect him, that's not a good sign - it means he already numbed himself looking too much :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dinonline](https://dinonline.org/2011/10/02/walking-behindbetween-women/) provides several answers for this Gemara (actually, there are two).

The article quotes the Arizal, and says that it refers only to the distance of 4 amos of the woman, and:

> one may be lenient in this matter, if one is confident that this will not lead to forbidden (promiscuous) thoughts.

> Some authorities, including Rav Shlomo Zalman Auerbach zt”l, wrote that one can be more lenient today. The reason given by Rav Shlomo Zalman is that it is virtually impossible, in a crowded road, to avoid walking behind a women; if one overtakes one woman, one will find oneself behind another. However, one should be particular about the matter where possible.

Comment: Might be worth quoting the opinion that the minimum distance is "beyond sight"?

Comment: Well now the question becomes, back then when this prohibition was relevant, what was the minimum distance?